# Raphael.svg returns false in IE9

Tags: javascript, raphael

Microsoft states that "With Internet Explorer 9, Microsoft is proud to introduce support for the basic SVG feature set. The SVG support in Internet Explorer 9 is based on the SVG 1.1 (Second Edition) specification recommendation (for desktop browsers)."
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410107.aspx)

Raphael.svg returns false in IE9.  Raphael docs state that Raphael.svg is "true if browser supports SVG".

So is IE9 actually rendering with VML or what?  Whatever IE9 is doing it's choking on my Raphael animation while all other browsers are running it smoothly.

Yes Chrome Frame is a possible solution, but with its attendant difficulties as well.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the HTML5 doctype.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`